# How to use webp in amp correctly

Tags: amp-html, webp, amp-img

I'm wondering how to use webp in amp correctly. There is a sample form [amp doc](https://www.ampproject.org/docs/design/responsive/responsive_design#providing-optimized-images)

```
<amp-img alt="Mountains"
width="550"
height="368"
layout="responsive"
src="images/mountains.webp">
<amp-img alt="Mountains"
    fallback
    width="550"
    height="368"
    layout="responsive"
    src="images/mountains.jpg"></amp-img>
</amp-img>
```

But this waste with bandwidth for non-webp browsers. A non-webp browser will download both images, first the webp, then failing to decode it, and download the jpg.

I know the AMP Cache does do webp transcoding automatically for webp capable browsers, but this doesn't help on my own origin or in other viewers.

There is also issue [Add mechanism for selecting image file based on capability](https://github.com/ampproject/amphtml/issues/3517), but it's inactive for two years.

Is there any better solution for this?